# How will we ignore duplicates while insert json data into mongoDB based on multiple condition

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, duplicates

```
[
{
    "RollNo":1,
    "name":"John",
    "age":20,
    "Hobby":"Music",
    "Date":"9/05/2018"
    "sal":5000
},

{
    "RollNo":2,
    "name":"Ravi",
    "age":25,
    "Hobby":"TV",
    "Date":"9/05/2018"
    "sal":5000
},
{
    "RollNo":3,
    "name":"Devi",
    "age":30,
    "Hobby":"cooking",
    "Date":"9/04/2018"
    "sal":5000
} 
]
```

Above is the JSON file i need to insert into a MongoDB. Similar JSON data  is already in my mongoDB collection named 'Tests'.I have to ignore the records which is already 
in the mongoDB based on a certain condition.

> *[RollNo in mongoDB == RollNo in the json need to insert && Hobby in mongoDB ==Hobby in the json need to insert && Date  in mongoDB == Date in the json need to insert]*.

**If this condition matches, i need to igore the insertion,else need to insert the data into DB** .

I am using nodejs. Anyone please help me to do it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose then use [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter).

```
db.people.update(
  { RollNo: 1 },
  {
      "RollNo":1,
      "name":"John",
      "age":20,
      "Hobby":"Music",
      "Date":"9/05/2018"
      "sal":5000
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

But to avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use upsert: true if the query field is uniquely indexed.

Comment: Hi @Ridham Tarpara,

I need to check the rollnumber,hobby and date.
if all are same,i will ignore. So does the query is like { RollNo: 1 ,Hobby :1, Date:1} ?

Comment: //Pseudo code

**If RollNo && Hobby && Date Exists:
    Then Skip, No insertion.
else:
    Add item**

Comment: @Aadi yes that is normal mongo query, you can do thay

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way to do this is by using a compound index.
You can create a compound index like this:

```
db.people.createIndex( { "RollNo": 1, "Hobby": 1, "Date" : 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Then the duplicated inserts will produce an error which you need to process in your code.